# How to update javascript file with function url from Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I currently have a Terraform file that is used to set up a website with s3 and CloudFront. My website has a dynamic component with Lambda Function URL that adds to a Dynamo DB table when my website is viewed. Everything works good, but my problem is I don't know how to get the function URL after Terraform is complete to automatically update in my javascript file, if this is possible or any other way. Right now, I have to go into the Javascript file and copy and paste the function URL from Lambda after my Terraform has ran, but I would like everything to be fully automated.

My javascript file(XXX= the function url that I have to hardcode):

```js
const counter = document.querySelector(".counter-number"); 
async function updateCounter() {
    let response = await fetch("XXX");
    let data = await response.json();
    counter.innerHTML = `Website View Count: ${data}`;
} 
updateCounter();
```

The portion of my Terraform where the Javascript file is uploaded to S3 - I currently have it to where any change in my website files is picked up through Terraform:

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "website_contents" {
  for_each     = fileset("/Users/andrea/Documents/AWS/CRC/my_website", "**") 
  bucket       = data.aws_s3_bucket.main_bucket.id
  key          = each.key
  source       = "/Users/andrea/Documents/AWS/CRC/my_website/${each.value}"
  content_type = each.value
  etag = filemd5("/Users/andrea/Documents/AWS/CRC/my_website/${each.value}")
}
```

Please let me know if there is any thing else I can provide, I appreciate any sort of help and assistance- thank you!

Comment: And where is that JS file?

Comment: @MarkoE /Users/andrea/Documents/AWS/CRC/my_website/index.js

Comment: Where does this "XXX' (a URL) come from? Is it generated by Terraform? This is not clear from your question.

Comment: @user2314737 "XXX"= my function url from lambda. It is created in my main.tf file under 'resource "aws_lambda_function_url"'. Currently, once my terraform files run- I have to grab the function URL from the Lambda console and manually put it in "XXX" in my javascript file. I would like to automate this process if possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is to save the `function_url` in a variable and then use this variable to edit a local file using `sed` with a [`local-exec` provisioner](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec). Hope this helps!

The resource [`lambda_function_url`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function_url#attribute-reference) exports three attributes:

- `function_arn` The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the function.
- `function_url` The HTTP URL endpoint for the function in the format https://<url_id>.lambda-url..on.aws.
- `url_id` A generated ID for the endpoint.

This means that the resource provides certain pieces of information that can be used by other parts of your Terraform configuration. These attributes can be referenced and used in other resources or data blocks.

Assuming you have something like this in your `.tf` files:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test" {
  filename      = "lambda_function_payload.zip"
  function_name = "my_lambda_function_name"
  # . . .
  # etc.
}

resource "aws_lambda_function_url" "my_lambda_function_url" {
  function_name      = aws_lambda_function.test.function_name
  authorization_type = "NONE"
}
```

You can define a variable `myURL`

```
# Use the exported function_url attribute in a variable
variable "myURL" {
  value = aws_lambda_function_url.my_lambda_function_url.function_url
}
```

And here's the code to edit the file ./my_website/myfile.js

```
resource "null_resource" "edit_file" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
      sed -i.bak "s|^const apiUrl =.*|const apiUrl = \"$URL\";|" ./my_website/myfile.js
    EOF
    environment = {
      URL = var.myURL 
    }
  }
  # this is needed to have script run every time
  triggers = {
    always_run = timestamp()
  }
}

# Optional: Output the content of the edited file
data "local_file" "edited_file" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.edit_file]
  filename   = "./my_website/myfile.js"
}

output "edited_file_content" {
  value = data.local_file.edited_file.content
}


variable "myURL" {
  type = string
  default = "https://example.comx/api?parameter=xyz"
}
```

This will substitute the URL using `sed` in a file `myfile.js` looking like this:

```
cat >./my_website/myfile.js <<EOF
// filename: myfile.js
const apiUrl = "abc";
console.log(apiUrl);
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the option given in the previous question, let me give you another option you can consider.

### Injecting views count as a query parameter

Since you've already using CloudFront, you may consider to convert your Web-facing Lambda function into Lambda.Edge function and connect it to the CloudFront Distribution you have as a `viewer-request` handler.

This way you will be able to rewrite request before it gets processed by the origin.

The code for your Lambda.Edge might look like the following:

```js
'use strict';

exports.handler = (evt, context, cb) => {
  const { request } = evt.Records[0].cf;

  // CUT: Get and update views count with DynamoDB
  // const viewsCount = 'xxx';

  request.querystring += `&viewsCount=${viewsCount}`;

  cb(null, request);
}
```

Your frontend code can be simplified, since views count will be provided as a query parameter, so no need to call a Lambda:

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const counter = document.querySelector(".counter-number"); 
counter.innerHTML = urlParams['viewsCount'] || '<default_value>';
```